# Loosing Mu's if you do the "Jetlink" on Multilayer fields

Tags: ingress

When you do a multilayer fields you are get XXX Mu's, so, when they pass the checkpoint, you add this to the global layer.

Lets supose 2 fields. First 10.000Mus, and second 20.000Mus.
So at checpoint I get 30.000Mus to the counter.

What happens if I do the "Jetlink"? Is suposed I get 4 fields int total..

1. 10.000
2. 20.000
3. (lets supose)5.000
4. (lets supose)5.000

So in total is counted 40.000 Mus to the check point? or only 20.000+5.000+5.000

I add a image as example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 40000 Mu counted at checkpoint.

Tested it a few days ago with 7 layers totaling 1.3 million MU.

Comment: On big fields, usually fields 3&4 on your diagram are much smaller than 1&2. But you sometime have a very flat 1, and either 3 or 4 is big. In each case the checkpoint count all layers, so the fields 1, 2, 3 and 4 all count.